# How can I create the "labCounter" MS access query for a given FKEY that could be the patient identifier

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I create the `labCounter` illustrated here on a MS access query, basically the lab counter will count consecutively the number of tests for a given FKEY that could be the patient identifier

This is ms-access

```
SELECT dbo_LabTests.PatientId, dbo_LabTests.LabDate, dbo_LabTests.LabTest,
       dbo_LabTests.LabResult, RowNumber([dbo_labtests_1]![patientid]) AS RowCount
FROM dbo_LabTests INNER JOIN dbo_LabTests AS dbo_LabTests_1 
ON dbo_LabTests.LabTestId = dbo_LabTests_1.LabTestId
WHERE (((dbo_LabTests.LabTest)="psa"));
```

It runs but provides consecutive number of rows and does not reset by FKEY

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that no two tests occur on the same day (else you'll receive the same count for both), you could use a correlated subquery with the `count` aggregate function, e.g.:

```
select 
    t.patientid, 
    t.labdate, 
    t.labtest, 
    t.labresult, 
    (
        select count(*) from dbo_labtests u 
        where 
            u.patientid = t.patientid and
            u.labtest = "psa" and
            u.labdate <= t.labdate
    ) as labcounter
from 
    dbo_labtests t
where
    t.labtest = "psa"
```

Comment: I'm getting this select 
    dbo_labtests!patientid, 
    dbo_labtests!!labdate, 
    dbo_labtests!labtest, 
    dbo_labtests!labresult, 
    (
        select count(*) from labtests u 
        where 
            u.patientid = dbo_labtests!patientid and
            u.labtest = "psa" and
            u.labdate <= dbo_labtests!labdate and
    ) as labcounter
from 
    dbo_labtests
where
    dbo_labtests!labtest = "psa"

Comment: Get an error when running the select count(*).... part

Comment: dbo_labtests is the name of the table

Comment: I've edited my answer to fix the table name and another typo.